# Is there a way to set different values to multiple lanes of a vector at a time using ARM NEON Intrinsics?

Tags: optimization, arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

Is it possible to set different values to multiple lanes of a vector at a time using ARM NEON Intrinsics?

For example, Instead of doing like

```
int32x2_t a, b, c, d, e, f;

.......... a few other operations...................

int *val;

...............val is pointing to another variable......

for(int i=0;i<var1;i++)
{
a = vset_lane_s32(val1[i], a, 0);
a = vset_lane_s32(val2[i], a, 1);
b = vset_lane_s32(val3[i], b, 0);
b = vset_lane_s32(val4[i], b, 1);
c = vset_lane_s32(val5[i], c, 0);
c = vset_lane_s32(val6[i], c, 1);
d = vset_lane_s32(val7[i], d, 0);
d = vset_lane_s32(val8[i], d, 1);

few operations based on a,b,c, and d
}
```

The values from val1 to val7 change in every loop iteration. Is there any other optimal way of initializing?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to load different lanes of a vector with different values using a single NEON intrinsic requires the values to be on contiguous memory addresses, i.e you would need an array of two int32_t values with which you would use the `vld1_s32` intrinsic to load the vector lanes.

Since from you code snippet it seems you need to take the values for different lanes from different arrays, you cannot use the `vld1_s32` intrinsic and thus you cannot initialize each of your vectors with a single NEON intrinsic.